# selenium can't open chrome browser on win7 in python?

Tags: python, windows-7, selenium

I am trying to open chrome browser with selenium webdriver in python on Windows 7 but it hangs. Below is the code I used:

`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
import time
from pprint import pprint

chromeOps = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
print "after chrome opts", chromeOps
print dir(chromeOps)
pprint(chromeOps)
chromeOps.binary_location = "C:\\Users\\cvoicu\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"

print "after binary loc"
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Python27\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chromeOps)
print "after browser", browser
print dir(browser)
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
```

`

Can you help me please? Thank you!

Comment: I see you have some debug code in there.  What call is it hanging on?  And are you getting any errors output?

Comment: There aren't any errors.Here you have the 2 last lines of output before hanging:
after binary loc
service url http://localhost:64960

Comment: Sometimes it reach the end, but it doesn't open the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
chromeOps = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
print "after chrome opts", chromeOps
print dir(chromeOps)
pprint(chromeOps)
chromeOps.binary_location = "C:\\Users\\cvoicu\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"

print "after binary loc"
```

See what happens now. When I instantiate chrome, i just set the path to the chromedriver and it works fine for me, also, might be a perms issue running the chrome driver in Python27, try moving that somewhere else as well

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried with those includes and 'browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe")', but nothing happens. In task manager I can see that it opens chromedriver, but no chrome process. Did you run it on Win7?

Comment: Also I have to specify that I have win7 on 64 bit platform. Can this be a problem for chromedriver to open chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes, taking out the ChromeOpts, because I don't have that file on my PC, and it works for me. Make sure that you add the chromedriver to `PATH` and you should be fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
import time
from pprint import pprint
import os



chromedriver = "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

print "after binary loc"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
print "after browser", browser
print dir(browser)
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
```